# Python nested for loop to split a file into lines then each line into variables

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, split, nested

I need to read in a file which has multiple data line as follows:

```
1 D 65.33383 BAZ 308.1043 Year 2001 Month 01 Day 01 Lat 6.90 Long 126.58 Mag 6.4 Origin Time 06:57:04.2
```

I need to split the file into lines, which I have done, then split each line into variables at each space.

So far I am using a nested loop that looks like:

```
for line in open("filename", 'r').readlines():
 variable = string.split(line)

 values = [variable]
 for value in values
 value = string.split(' ')
 year, month = value[0], value [1]
```

My problem is that I don't know what the parts in the second for loop need to be? i.e for ... in ...

I am quite new to programming in python.

Comment: You mean that each paired two words are a key-value pair? Why not use a dictionary?

Comment: The format uses spaces in the `Origin Time` key. Are you certain there are no tabs in that format? That'd make the items easier to parse at least.

Comment: I think `Origin Time 06:57:04.2` shows can't rely on `str.split()` alone to split variable names and values. What is the 1 at the beginning of the data line for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not fully sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, one thing that is especially unclear is your expression:  "then split each line into variables at each space".

But assuming you need to get the output which consists of a list of dictionaries each containing parsed data from the line the following should be useful for you:

```
data = []
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        lineData = {}
        lineSplit = line.split()
        for i in range(1,len(lineSplit)-1,2):
            lineData[lineSplit[i]] = lineSplit[i+1]
        data.append(lineData)
print data
```

This will get you the output which will look like this:

```
[{'Origin': 'Time', 'D': '65.33383', 'BAZ': '308.1043', 'Long': '126.58', 'Month': '01', 'Mag': '6.4', 'Year': '2001', 'Lat': '6.90', 'Day': '01'}]
```

The dictionary is unsorted so keys and values appear in random order. Notice that Origin time became keys and values because you wanted to split the line on space and there is a space between origin and times.  Cheers!

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Some of the parts of the line in the original file I want use at a later stage. So for each line that I have split, I need to split again to take some of the values. So once I have split for the second time I need the parts to be assigned a name. Thanks

Comment: Okay, can you give an example of how your final output should look?

Comment: There is no output. I want to take the values for lat, long (and some of the others) and then insert them into a java client to download data. So eventually the program should form a line that looks like: java -jar GeoNetCWBQuery-4.0.2-bin.jar -s "NZ.....HH..." -d 3600 -event:time "2008/07/05 02:12:05" -event:lat "53.88" -event:lon "152.89" -event:depth "632" where each value in "" has been taken from the original file, and then run this in the konsole command line.

Comment: Well I don't know about inserting things to java client, but in case of Python dictionaries, if you'll have Python dict that look like the one above you can easily access values by doing lineData["Long"] or lineData["Month"] (but if dicts are in a list of course you'll have to loop over them) etc.

Comment: Hi Pawelmhm, could you explain accessing the values in a bit more detail? For example, If i want to print just the Lat of the first line, how would I do that?

Comment: If you want to print just the lat you can simply do lineData["Lat"]

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as data:
    for _input in data:
        line = _input.split(' ')
        data = {'Index':line[0],
                'Origin Time':line[-3:][-1].strip()
                }
        data.update(dict(zip(line[1:-3][0::2], line[1:-3][1::2])))
        print data
```

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Comment: I was wrong, you dont need pyparsing. Use code in edited answer version.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, using a regular expression is probably the easiest, since some of your entries contain spaces.

The following expression finds anything that is *not* digits, followed by something that consists only of digits, dots and colons:

```
import re
key_val = re.compile(r'\s*([^\d]+)\s+([\d.:]+)\s*')

mapping = dict(key_val.findall(line))
```

This produces a dictionary object:

```
>>> import re
>>> line = '1 D 65.33383 BAZ 308.1043 Year 2001 Month 01 Day 01 Lat 6.90 Long 126.58 Mag 6.4 Origin Time 06:57:04.2\n'
>>> key_val = re.compile(r'\s*([^\d]+)\s+([\d.:]+)\s*')
>>> key_val.findall(line)
[('D', '65.33383'), ('BAZ', '308.1043'), ('Year', '2001'), ('Month', '01'), ('Day', '01'), ('Lat', '6.90'), ('Long', '126.58'), ('Mag', '6.4'), ('Origin Time', '06:57:04.2')]
>>> dict(key_val.findall(line))
{'D': '65.33383', 'BAZ': '308.1043', 'Long': '126.58', 'Month': '01', 'Origin Time': '06:57:04.2', 'Mag': '6.4', 'Year': '2001', 'Lat': '6.90', 'Day': '01'}
```